# Figure from Mathematica is printed on separate page

Tags: floats, positioning, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to include a Mathematica code in LaTeX. To do that, I just exported the code as PDF. The thing is that when I am trying to include the PDF figure in my TeX code, the figure is printed on the next page.

The code I am using is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\nonumber W_{r\rightarrow\infty}=&-\int_{r}^{\infty}\!F\,\mathrm{d}y=-\int_r^\infty \!     \dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \dfrac{q^2}{\alpha^2} \dfrac{\alpha^3}{y^3}\left(1-    \dfrac{\alpha^2}{y^2}\right)^{-2}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
=&-\dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \dfrac{q^2}{\alpha^2}\alpha^3 \underbrace{\int_r^\infty     \! y^{-3} \left(1-\dfrac{\alpha^2}{y^2}\right)^{-2} \,\mathrm{d}y}_{I} \label{eq:WcondI}
\end{align}

\begin{figure}[H]%
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{math}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The image can be downloaded from here
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19828093/math.pdf

Any ideas on that?

Comment: The `H` option is defined by the `float` package. If you want the image there with no caption, just use the `center` environment and not `figure`.

Comment: @egreg:I didn't know...I should have, though...Thank you very much for the educative information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[H]` option is only defined by the `float` package. In your case, the unknown option is changed into `[p]`.

However you don't need at all a `figure` environment, since you don't have a caption. The `\includegraphics` command can go everywhere, even in math.

With the following code you will be sure that the Mathematica code will never be detached from the equation (unless you allow it with `\displaybreak`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{split}
W_{r\rightarrow\infty}
&=
  -\int_{r}^{\infty} F \diff y=
  -\int_r^\infty \dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \dfrac{q^2}{\alpha^2} \dfrac{\alpha^3}{y^3}
    \left(1-\dfrac{\alpha^2}{y^2}\right)^{-2}\diff y\\
&=
  -\dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \dfrac{q^2}{\alpha^2}\alpha^3
    \underbrace{\int_r^\infty y^{-3} \left(1-\dfrac{\alpha^2}{y^2}\right)^{-2} \diff y}_{I}
\end{split}
\label{eq:WcondI}
\\[2ex]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{math}\notag
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Notice how I corrected your input of the equation, that shows some flaws.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`[H]` is not defined by default. I'd simply recommend writing `[htp]` instead, works just as well, but the float will move if there is no room for it, and the rest of the page will be used for text.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I replaced `H` with `h!` and it's working. What do you mean that "[H] is not defined by default"? I thought that `H` and `h!` are the same... Perhaps I am mistaken!

Comment: It's not the same. AFAIR the `here` package defines `H`

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen From `texdoc here` one learns that "The original `here.sty` by David Carlisle was withdrawn many years ago. The `[H]` modifier is now implemented in `float.sty`, which this `here.sty` simply reads."

Comment: @egreg, I guess it should go into `L2Tabu` then. I'll check it.